# Get what's remaining after a slice using numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a numpy matrix where one row for example looks like the following:

```
|0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8|
```

I can get a certain piece of the array eg. `[3,4,5]` which I need for one purpose using numpy slicing `a[0,3:6]`.

Is there anything builtin that will allow me to also get everything not in that range with it? Like `[0,1,2,6,7,8]`

Comment: Range by index or value?  With your example we can't tell the difference.

Comment: The range is by index eg. positions 3:6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach with [`boolean indexing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays) -

```
a[~np.in1d(np.arange(a.size),r)]
```

Sample run -

```
In [174]: a
Out[174]: array([10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18])

In [175]: r
Out[175]: [3, 4, 5]

In [176]: a[~np.in1d(np.arange(a.size),r)]  # Without r
Out[176]: array([10, 11, 12, 16, 17, 18])

In [177]: a[r]  # With r
Out[177]: array([13, 14, 15])
```

Another with [`integer array indexing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#index-arrays) -

```
a[np.setdiff1d(np.arange(a.size),r)]
```

Another way would be concatenating slices on either sides of the original slice -

```
np.concatenate((a[:r[0]], a[r[-1]+1:]))
```

Answer (score 2):

There's some ambiguity in your question and example.  Are you selecting elements by value or index?  And should we take `slice` literally?

Taking `slice` literally:

```
In [10]: x=np.arange(10)   # stick with the ambiguous input for now
In [11]: x[3:6]
Out[11]: array([3, 4, 5])
```

`np.delete` is a handy tool if selecting elements by position.  It's general purpose, and can use `slice` as well as `list` inputs:

```
In [13]: np.delete(x,slice(3,6))
Out[13]: array([0, 1, 2, 6, 7, 8, 9])
In [14]: np.delete(x,[3,4,5])
Out[14]: array([0, 1, 2, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

`np.in1d` is useful if you want to select elements by value.

Boolean masking is also a good tool to know and use.

---

`delete` uses different methods depending on the inputs.  For a simple slice I believe it uses the equivalent of:

```
In [15]: np.concatenate((x[:3],x[6:]))
Out[15]: array([0, 1, 2, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

Comment: `np.in1d` can also be used for selecting by index, using range of indices.

Comment: does `np.delete` mutate the original array in some cases?

Comment: `np.delete` returns a new array.  You can't remove elements from an array in-place.  Its size is fixed.  A `slice` is a view, but the `delete` result has to be a copy (it's a non contiguous subset of the original values).